# LaTeX two-column figure shows up underneath text

Tags: latex

I'm trying to add this two-column image a the top of this page; however, it shows up underneath the text.

```
    \begin{figure*}[htb!]
    \label{fig:2}
    \includegraphics[trim=0cm 3.5in 0cm 3.5in,clip=true, width=6in]{2}
    \caption{asdfasdf}
    \end{figure*}
```

Without the [!] the image goes to the next page, and with [H] and `\usepackage{float}` the image doesn't appear at all. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Here is the rest of the code:

```
\documentclass[aps,twocolumn,secnumarabic,balancelastpage,amsmath,amssymb,nofootinbib]{revtex4}



\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{chapterbib}    % allows a bibliography for each chapter (each labguide has it's own)
\usepackage{color}         % produces boxes or entire pages with colored backgrounds
\usepackage{graphics}      % standard graphics specifications
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}      % alternative graphics specifications
\usepackage{longtable}     % helps with long table options
\usepackage{epsf}          % old package handles encapsulated post script issues
\usepackage{bm}            % special 'bold-math' package
\usepackage{verbatim}           % for comment environment
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}  % this package should be added after all others
                                        

\begin{document}

Blah Blah Text

\begin{figure*}[htb]
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 4.4in 0cm 4.4in,clip=true, width=6in]{ringdown_freqscan}
\caption{Left:Blah Blah}
\label{fig:rdfs}
\end{figure*}

MORE TEXT

\par

Designed by UF researchers, the suck stick is inserted into the top 
of the dewar and contains a port at its top to pump out its inside. 
At the 

\begin{figure*}[htb!]
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 3.5in 0cm 3.5in,clip=true, width=6in]{damp_freq}
\caption{asdfasdf}
\label{fig:damp_freq}
\end{figure*}
very base of the suck stick is a capillary intended to allow a very
specific amount of the contents of the dewar into the cryostat where


MORE TEXT

\end{document}
```

The second figure is sandwiched in the middle of the sentence because that is the point at which a new page begins.

I should add that I was able to do this with the first image as seen here:
[correct image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bu0Mv.png)

Comment: Here is an image of what happens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xJqM.png

Comment: As to the problem with `\label` and `\ref`, you need to add the `\label` after `\caption`.

Comment: Did you load the `flushend`package? I think this can cause the problem.

Comment: By the way, you may find the sister site of StackOverflow [TeX - LaTeX StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) very useful in dealing with LaTeX related problems. :-)

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry thank you! that fixed the reference problem! Unfortunately, I don't have `flushend` loaded. Any other ideas? Also, would it be better if I reposted this straight to TeX?

Comment: Well, I think the problem can be directly solved here if you provide some additional details. For example, your documentclass. It would be even better if you post a full working example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that can show the problem you encounter.

Comment: I've got it. It is the problem with `trim` and `clip`.

Comment: Ah okay! I posted the bulk of the code in an answer since it was too long to type in a comment. Thank you!

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry I also added a screenshot of the first figure, which works perfectly.

Comment: The floot environment for `revtex` seems to have many issues (which I did not use before). It is even more strange this version (`revtex4`) does not compile with a two column document. I am on Ubuntu 20 with TeX Live 2021. (Maybe experts on TeX - StackExchange will have a clue.)

Comment: Turns out it was an issue with the `trim` function! with all entries at 0 it works perfectly! thanks for all your help!